# Modal Window When Clicking Link Button

Tags: asp.net, modalpopups

I have a LinkButton inside a data list. When I click on this LinkButton, I want to open a modal window and load another html page in it.

Can you guys please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You should check out a jQuery plugin like [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/), which I've used to do exactly what you've described.

Answer (score 0):

check ModalPopupExtender....It's a component of Ajax Control toolkit.
First download it from from [CodePlex](http://www.Codeplex.com) ....and when you add reference the *Binary.dll to your project...you can use it within your pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have always been a big fan of YUI, they have great documentation and Examples showing how to set things up. [ i love jQuery too ].

Look at YUI's Container Objects. They have very slick skinable Modal Panels:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/container/panel/

Here is a simple example:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/panel-loading.html

Server Side

```
button.Attributes.Add("click", "popModal");
```

Client Side

```
<script>
    function popModal(e) {
        // Initialize the temporary Panel to display while waiting for external content to load
        var SavingPanel =
                        new YAHOO.widget.Panel("wait",
                            { width: "240px",
                                fixedcenter: true,
                                close: false,
                                draggable: false,
                                zindex: 1000,
                                modal: true,
                                visible: true
                            }
                        );

        SavingPanel.setHeader("Saving, please wait...");
        SavingPanel.setBody('<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/per/gr/gp/rel_interstitial_loading.gif"  />');
        SavingPanel.render(document.body);

    }
</script>
```